# In MySQL, what does this mean? /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 */

Tags: mysql

```
 /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 */
```

1. Why is it between comment marks?
2. What is the 40100 all about?
3. What is the ! for?
4. What does it do?
5. Where is the documentation for this?

Comment: @MarcusAdams, these comments appear usually during export to `SQL` file from any number of mysql clients

Answer (score 33, accepted):

1. It's a conditional comment that can be interpreted by MySQL
2. The code 40100 means only these versions of MySQL>=4.1.0 (4.01.00) will interpret the conditional comment.
3. The `!` is here to force MySQL to parse the code between the `/* ... */`
4. It sets the value of the parameter DEFAULT CHARACTER = 'latin1' so that the data in an SQL dump can be intepreted correctly during import.  It doesn't affect the database structure, but merely helps the export/import process to work right.
5. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/comments.html